# Выпадающее меню (три точки) из Toolbar темное и поверх самого Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

При нажатии меню (три точки) в тулбар появляется меню, но темного фона.

Причем выскакивает оно не под тулбаром, а сверху, тем самым перекрывая тулбар.

Подскажите, куда смотреть? Нутром чую, что в темы, но не нашел.

[image: Черная область и есть меню после нажатия три точки]

Answer (score 2):

Оно и не должно выскакивать под туобаром т.к. это компонент тулбара , то и выскакивает на тулбаре. Что бы изменить `background` меню нужно переопределить стиль меню и задать любой цвет или смотреть какую тему заюзали в стилях для апк - например `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: У меня основная тема приложения/активности - Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Стиль Toolbar - ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar. Что мне нужно перекрыть? Как называется элемент - выпадающее меню?

Comment: Есть контекстное меню на ListView - там цвет фона не черный. Если изменить основную тему приложения, то везде поменяется?